# Symfony3 http_auth on nginx - browser did not show any http auth dialog box

Tags: nginx, symfony, http-authentication

I am learning symfony3 based on symfony book instructions with nginx configured for.

the problem is that when i try to reach to /admin (that configured in security.yml for http authentication) i see an error message instead of a http auth dialog box!

I think this is a problem about nginx and symfony together!

What should i do for solving this?

Comment: Do you mean [these Nginx instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#nginx)? If so, can you check the `/var/log/nginx/project_error.log` file and see what it says? We need to know the error.

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you supplied the exact error you're getting.

Comment: @AlvinBunk I see this error "Full authentication is required to access this resource" and there is not any error about this in /var/log/nginx/{my_project}_error.log